# Discord bot unable to get access to the Google Sheets getting error The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, discord.js, google-sheets-api

I am having problem with my Discord bot trying to access the Google Sheets API v4.0. I want it to read, write, and update data in the sheet. My code work fine for Node.js application but when I put my code in a Discord bot, it gives me this error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The request is missing a valid API key`

I don't understand why I am getting this error. I even made a service account for my Discord bot.

Here is the Discord bot's code.

```
require('dotenv').config();

const sheet = require('./sheet');
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const { sheets } = require('googleapis/build/src/apis/sheets');
const client = new Client();
```

Sheet file code:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const keys = require('./keys.json');

const client  = new google.auth.JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    keys.private_key_id,
    keys.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
);

client.authorize(function(err,tokens){

    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    // else{
    //     console.log('Connected');
    //     gsrun(client);
    // }
});

const getdata = async function gsrun(cl){

    const gsapi = google.sheets({version:'v4',auth:cl});

    const opt = {
        spreadsheetId:'1LzdhD4rb2FdElTyQCAkgb5oyeGeu0d9rT2abS4n_4i8',
        range: 'A2:B5'
    };

    let data =  await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);

    console.log(data.data.values);
}
exports.getdata = getdata;
```

I have given access to bot email id to sheet which is discordbotapi@nodejs-api-testing-discordbot.iam.gserviceaccount.com. I have also enabled the Google Sheets API. Where am I making error?

Comment: How do you call `getdata()`? It looks like you never passed the token received in `client.authorize()`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I don't know but it worked perfectly fine in node js application. Problem comes when I use my code in discord .js There it is giving me this weired errors!

Comment: I think it was running fine because you called it like `gsrun(client)` once it was authorised. Now, you only export a function, without any authorisation, and I don't think you pass the `client` once you import `getdata`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros So according to you I should export my authorization to with it and then authorize it there. What should be the approach here to solve it.

Comment: @COdeingNinja I have a discord bot that has the same premise where it uses the googleapis to append info to a spreadsheet. What I did was create separate functions, one for collecting messages via Discord, and then one for the googleapi appending function. Then I just made a global variable containing the array and passed it onto the appending function. Might be an alternate method to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tried it in Node.js without Discord.js, you didn't export anything and you simply called `gsrun(client)` after the authorisation was successful, so it worked fine. The problem is that now you try to use `getData` without any authorisation. Although you have `client.authorize` in your code, you never use it.

To solve this, I would make at least two different functions here; one for generating the client and one for the get request itself and export them both.

To generate a client I’d wrap this in a promise. This way I could use async/await later. This function will create a client with the JWT, perform the authorisation, and either resolve with the client or reject the promise depending on the results of `client.authorize()`.

```js
function connect() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
    const { client_email, private_key, private_key_id } = keys;
    const client = new google.auth.JWT(
      client_email,
      private_key_id,
      private_key,
      scope,
    );

    client.authorize((err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(client);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Now you can simply connect and get the client by using `const client = await connect()`.

The second part is to get some data from the spreadsheet. Again, I'd wrap it in a promise. This function will accept the client (we’ve just created above) and the options with the spreadsheetId and range. Inside the promise you just call the API endpoint with the options:

```js
function getData(client, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const endpoint = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: client });

    endpoint.spreadsheets.values.get(options, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        // or resolve with data.data.values if you only want the values
        resolve(data.data);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

You can export both of these in an object. Here is the full `sheet.js` file:

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const keys = require('./keys.json');

function connect() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
    const { client_email, private_key, private_key_id } = keys;
    const client = new google.auth.JWT(
      client_email,
      private_key_id,
      private_key,
      scope,
    );

    client.authorize((err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(client);
      }
    });
  });
}

function getData(client, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const endpoint = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: client });

    endpoint.spreadsheets.values.get(options, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data.data);
      }
    });
  });
}

module.exports = { connect, getData };
```

Then, you can import it in your bot's file and use it in there to connect first and then get the values:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const { connect, getData } = require('./sheet');

const client = new Client();

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const auth = await connect();

  const options = {
    spreadsheetId: '1LzdhD4rb2FdElTyQCAkgb5oyeGeu0d9rT2abS4n_4i8',
    range: 'A2:B5',
  };
  const { values } = await getData(auth, options);

  message.channel.send(values);
});
```