# Can i use excel as a database for my discord bot? And how?

Tags: discord.js

I'm fairly new to making discord bots and I'm trying to make a database to store data about users which can be edited through code. I've tried using **MONGODB** but everything was to confusing and I don't want to go back to it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Search for Excel Discord integration.

Comment: If MongoDB was confusing, I think working with spreadhseets will be the same. Anyway, (not Excel but Google Sheets), you'll need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167018/discord-bot-unable-to-get-access-to-the-google-sheets-getting-error-the-request/66170234#66170234

Answer (score 1):

Using Excel as a database is not a good practice, I don't know what language you are building your bots in, but I recommend that you use an easier database like MySQL or MariaDB, both are very similar and easy to understand, you can to look for some library in the language your bot is making, that works with all the data manipulation part of the database, if you are doing this NodeJs, I recommend using TypeORM, it is simple to understand and has a relatively syntax easy.

Documentations: 
Typeorm : https://typeorm.io/ 
MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/documentation/ 
Mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Answer (score 0):

No. Excel is a spreadsheet, not a database. I have no experience with discord bots, but I would have thought that you could easily install/configure MySQL on your local environment. Plenty of how tos on oracles site :)